# Basic Auth for WSO2 EI API service

Tags: basic-authentication, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2-EI 6.4.0. I have tried this development with [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Securing+APIs). It work for me. But I need to get user name and password from other back end service. In this example was showed the hard corded user and password. I have added that code for your reference. Please help me to get those user name and password from property file.

```
public boolean processSecurity(String credentials) {
        String decodedCredentials = new String(new Base64().decode(credentials.getBytes()));
        String usernName = decodedCredentials.split(":")[0];
        String password = decodedCredentials.split(":")[1];
        if ("admin".equals(username) && "admin".equals(password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

I have added WSO2 EI handler like following. I need to pass the value from back service or call other sequence and load.

```
<api context="/test">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
        ................
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
        ................
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>        
         <handler class="rezg.ride.common.BasicAuthHandler">
            <property name="cm_password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="cm_userName" value="admin"/>
         </handler>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

When we run the above API, handlers are running first and then running in and out sequences. So I need to get user name and password calling Sequence or any other method before run this BasicAuthHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the property file from the class mediator it's just straight forward java property file reading. Please refer the following call sample of reading a property file. In this scenario, Just read the carbon.properties file exists in the conf directory.

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        String passwordFileLocation = System.getProperty("conf.location")+"/carbon.properties";
        try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(passwordFileLocation)) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);
            log.info("------org.wso2.CipherTransformation : " + prop.getProperty("org.wso2.CipherTransformation"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
       return true;
    }
```

To get the server location and the conf locating, There are JAVA system properties are set at the time wso2 server starts. Following are some of the useful System system properties.

- carbon.local.ip
- carbon.home
- conf.location

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But I need  those data using Sequence call. Because I need this data from back end service, this user name and password data based on the request values.

Comment: Did you need to call another HTTP endpoint and get the values? In that case, You can use call mediator [1] for that.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Call+Mediator

Comment: Can I use that call mediator before call the handlers ??